# Verify items in a popup menu with espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a popup menu. User interface screenshot provided below. I want to verify some items in the menu by clicking them and verify what's happening.

No matter what I do, I am unable to select items in the popup menu. The menu does not have an ID and I don't think it's possible to set the ID of a menu.

I've tried different things like:

```java
onView(nthChildOf(anyOf(withId(android.R.id.title)), 1)).perform(click());

onView(withText("5 sekunder")).perform(click());
```

But nothing works. How do I click on an item in a popup menu?

##### EDIT

To be clearer: This happens when I click on the dots on the right side of the action bar to expand the sub-menu. The sub-menu in my case always consists of three items. The closest I've come to a solution is:

```
onData(anything()).atPosition(2).perform(click());
```

But most of the time it opens the first item and not the item in position two. This results in:

```
No activities in stage RESUMED. Did you forget to launch the activity. (test.getActivity() or similar)?
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: add logs, a screenshot of activity

Answer (score 16):

Espresso provides [RootMatchers](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/matcher/RootMatchers) for this case. It works well for me:

```java
onView(withText("Text")).inRoot(isPopupWindow()).perform(click());

public static Matcher<Root> isPopupWindow() {
    return isPlatformPopup();
}
```

[isPlatformPopup()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/matcher/RootMatchers#isPlatformPopup()) is a method in the [RootMatchers](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/matcher/RootMatchers) class. You can read more targeting non-default windows in the Android Developers documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/recipes#targeting-non-default-windows).

Or try this:

```
onView(withText("Text"))
  .inRoot(withDecorView(not(is(getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()))))
  .perform(click());
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11037599)

Comment: @innoSPG well, but it is really an answer to the question. If someone asks me "Hey, how can I click on an item in the popup menu?" again, I will say "use Espresso RootMatchers". And it will be a good answer to the question.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. Both alternatives give me following error: 

`No activities in stage RESUMED. Did you forget to launch the activity. (test.getActivity() or similar)?`

The only thing that seems to work is: 
`onData(anything()).atPosition(2).perform(click());`
but the problem with that is that it only works like half of the time. The other half it picks the first item in the list (index 0) and not the one I'm asking for.

Comment: Did you look at the UIX?

Comment: @peuhse It is very sad that it does not work:( When I face with similar issues, I ask developers of app "What the hell is this popup?" So probably it is best to have a look at the app code. If there is no adapterView in the popup, I assume onData will be not work here. Maybe it's a recycler view. Or a system popup (I use fake intents here). I hope you will find a solution soon!

Comment: This is also helpful for Spinners

Answer (score 1):

Can you try out the following code snippet?

```
  openActionBarOverflowOrOptionsMenu(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext());

  // Click the item.
  onView(withText("Menu1"))
    .perform(click());
```

Comment: Same problem. It opens the menu, but opens menu 1 even though a ask  for menu 2 (or 3) in `onView(withText("Menu 2")).perform(click());`

Answer (score 0):

If you get a handle on any one of the `TextView`s in the pop up menu, you'll see it has a parent hierarchy as follows:

```
PopUpWindow$PopupDecorView
  \-- PopUpWindow$PopupBackgroundView
    \-- MenuPopupWindow$MenuDropDownListView
      \-- ListMenuItemView
        \-- LinearLayout
          \-- RelativeLayout
            \-- TextView
```

Each item in the popup menu is contained within a `ListMenuItemView` and the parent of all these `ListMenuItemView`s is `MenuPopupWindow$MenuDropDownListView`.

You can use this knowledge to define a `withPositionInMenuDropDownListView(position:)` matcher method that matches the child View at a given position within a `MenuPopupWindow.MenuDropDownListView` instance, as follows:

```kotlin
fun withPositionInMenuDropDownListView(position: Int): Matcher<View> {
    return allOf(withParent(isMenuDropDownListView()), withParentIndex(position))
}

fun isMenuDropDownListView(): Matcher<View> {
    return anyOf(
        withClassName(equalTo("android.widget.MenuPopupWindow\$MenuDropDownListView")),
        withClassName(equalTo("androidx.appcompat.widget.MenuPopupWindow\$MenuDropDownListView"))
    )
}
```

You can then click on any one of the items in the popup menu as follows:

```kotlin
onView(withPositionInMenuDropDownListView(1)).perform(click())
```

If you wanted, you could also assert that the popup menu is showing the right number of items, as follows:

```kotlin
onView(isMenuDropDownListView()).checkMatches(hasChildCount(3)
```