# Appium PopupWindow (Android)

Tags: appium, appium-android

I'm unable to find a element inside a PopupWindow using Appium :(
I need to click in a element with especific id inside this popup-menu.
How can I do this?

At Expresso tests, the developers are using this matcher:

```
onView(withId(id)).inRoot(isPopupWindow()).perform(click());
public static Matcher<Root> isPopupWindow() {
        return isPlatformPopup();
}
```

[Verify items in a popup menu with espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35013172/verify-items-in-a-popup-menu-with-espresso)

Thanks

Comment: Could you please add the screenshot by inspecting the expected element(UIAutomatorViewer or any other inspector)

Answer (score 0):

Use AndroidUIAutomator to find the element by using the command

*driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("text(\"**Text**\")").click();*

if this does not help you can always use other methods to find elements like **ID, Classname** etc