# Click a PopupMenu button with Espresso?

Tags: kotlin, junit, android-view, android-espresso

Is there a way to click an item in an inflated PopupMenu anchored to a ListView item?

I have a PopupMenu that is created by clicking a button inside a ListView. I need to click an item inside the popup by id.

Here is my test:

```kotlin
val item = onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.profiles_list)).atPosition(index)
val menuButton = item.onChildView(withId(R.id.options_button))
menuButton.perform(click()) // This opens the popup (anchored to menuButton)
```

And here is how the menu is created after clicking options_button:

```kotlin
val popup = PopupMenu(context, menuButton)
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
    when (it.itemId) {
        R.id.profile_rename -> {
            // Action to perform
            true
        }
        else -> false
    }
}
popup.menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.list_item_profile, popup.menu)
popup.show()
```

I've tried using isPlatformPopup, which does not find the popup:

```kotlin
menuButton.inRoot(isPlatformPopup()).onChildView(withId(R.id.profile_rename)).perform(click())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the item could be retrieved using withText(), rather than with onChildView(withId())

```
onView(withText(R.string.rename)).inRoot(isPlatformPopup()).perform(click())
```

Based on the solution from [Verify items in a popup menu with espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35013172/verify-items-in-a-popup-menu-with-espresso)